# Add columns into a DataTable inside a loop

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, datatable

I'd like to know if there is a way to automatically add columns in a DataTable inside a foreach loop? That is what I mean with "automatically".

I had in mind something like this:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

foreach (var item in model.Statistik)
{
   dt.Columns.Add();
   row = dt.NewRow();
   row[//Name of column goes here] = // either item or item.property;
   dt.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

This is much more efficient than explicitly name every column before the for each loop. Because, what happens if some property changes or gets deleted, etc.? This is therefore, something I wish to get rid of.

Comment: Wat prevents you from using `row["ColumnName"]=value`? You don't know the properties of `item`? What type is it, can you show it?

Comment: I do know the properties of my ViewModel, but I'd like to simplify it a lot. Think if I am working with a lot of properties, hence, it is not so efficient? I had something in mind getting the DisplayName attributes of each property and then add that to the column in the loop code, so it matches the item next in line in the loop. So if I have a property of type string in my VM, the column would receive the item's attribute name so I can add it to the column. Because, I think you need to add a column matching the item's record.

Comment: This is what I thought about:

    dt.Columns.Add(attribute name of prop. goes here);
    row = dt.NewRow();
    row[attr. name of prop. goes here] = // either item or item.property;

In this way, I don't need to specify every time a new column outside the loop, neither in the row, the column's name.

Comment: What is the type of `model.Statistik` and/or `item`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you understand how `dt.Columns` and `dt.Rows` are related. There is one set of `Column`s for a `DataTable`. Every `Row` in the `DataTable` has all the matching columns - you don't have unique `Column`s in each `Row`. So every time you do `dt.Columns.Add` you are adding a column to every `Row`, old or new.

Also, how do you expect `Row[`<name of column>`]` to work if you don't specify the name to the `DataTable`?

Comment: What I want is to add columns and rows into a `DataTable` automatically inside a loop. I believe that, the normal procedure would be, to use `dt.Columns.Add("First Name");` and `dt.Rows.Add(model.FirstName);` and if I have many columns, I will have to specify every one of them, which can be annoying. So is there some way to automatize all of this? Because, that `model.Statistik`, is a list of type ViewModel. But the strange thing is, when I add this property to the `DataTable` directly, as per the example above, I get all the properties from the VM, and not only those specified in the list.